# Fixed effects logit lasso model

Tags: r

My data set has a binary dependent variable (0/1) and a lot of continuous independent variables for many individuals and three time periods. Therefore, I am facing a panel data set with a binary dependent variable, which asks for the use of a non-linear panel data model. However, I also have a lot of independent variables, which asks for the use of a variable selection method. Therefore, I want to apply lasso on a fixed effects logit model.

As far as I know, there is only the possibility in `cv.glmnet` to estimate a logit lasso model by the function `cv.glmnet(x, y, weights, offset, lambda, type.measure='binomial', nfolds, foldid, grouped, keep, parallel, ...)` using `type.measure='binomial'`. This estimation procedure pools all individuals as it is a cross-sectional estimation procedure and does not take the panel component of my data set.

Therefore, I would like to adjust the `cv.glmnet` function such that I can take as input for example `type.measure='fe binomial'` and so it runs a fixed effects logit lasso model.

In conclusion, it is possible to run a fixed effects logit model and a lasso model separately but I want to combine both. How can I do this in R?

(Also, in the attachment I wrote my model down in more detail)

[Explanation model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWfgq.jpg)

Comment: This is(in my opinion) too broad as it requires one to code the model from scratch. Could you show parts you've tried to write in R?

Comment: There is not a lot more relevant code I can give as my question is how to start with estimating a fixed effects logit lasso model. What kind of code would you like to see?